# (ActionMenu)W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed

Tags: java, android, menu, android-actionbar, popupmenu

I made Action Bar Menu App. But If I click menuitem, Toast Message is not shown.
I run the emulator and my phone. But It doesn't work. 
when I click menuitem, logcat is show error message:

```
W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
```

This is MY CODE:

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.info:
            Toast.makeText(this,"짠",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return true;
        case R.id.support:
            return true;
        default:
            return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
}
```

**res/menu/mymenu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:title="help"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/support"
    android:title="support"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you `Toast.makeText(this,"짠",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);` should `Toast.makeText(this,"짠",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` invoke `show()` method.Hope help you.